# How to clear panel's graphics in c#?

Tags: c#, graphics, panel

I have used grahics in a panel. At start of the program I draw some points in the panel and after that I want to draw lines connecting those points. Problem is when I press tab button the graphics created disappear (but this happens once in the program). Next problem is I want to clear the panel I used following code to clear panel:

```
Panel1.Invalidate();
```

But this only clears the lines but not those points that were initially created. Does anyone has a simple solution because I don't want to recreate the panel.

Technical Detail: to draw initial points in panel, paint event of `panel1` is used:

```
Graphics gfx = e.CreateGraphics()
```

For lines, there is a seprate function that is called on button click and in that I used:

```
Graphics gfx = Panel1.CreateGraphics();
```

Another button that is used to clear panel has following code:

```
Panel1.invalidate();
```

but it only clears the line graphics, not those initial points.

Comment: If you directly draw on the Panel using Panel.CreateGraphics(), you can not easily clean it. Did you consider using the Panel.Paint() event yet?

Comment: i draw point in the paint event of panel1 and use Graphics gfx = e.CreateGraphics(). For Lines i user Graphics gfx = Panel1.CreateGraphics(); and to clear panel i use Panel1.invalidate(); but it only clears the line graphics not the points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was making a mistake by creating initial points in the paint event of panel1. So everytime i call

```
Panel1.Invalidate();
```

it recalls that paint event and those points are redrawn and not cleared.

Answer (score 2):

Do you save the points in some sort of collection and draw them in the `Paint` event?

Then you should empty the collection and then call the `Invalidate`

Comment: i draw point in the paint event of panel1 and use Graphics gfx = e.CreateGraphics(). For Lines i user Graphics gfx = Panel1.CreateGraphics(); and to clear panel i use Panel1.invalidate(); but it only clears the line graphics not the points.

Comment: i have those points in a datatable and just read the xy axis from there. But it has nothing to do with the paint event.

Answer (score 0):

The panel is redrawn inside the paint event. It means that you have to draw everything inside this method, instead of accessing the graphics context directly.

This explains why everything you draw when you use `Graphics gfx = Panel1.CreateGraphics();` is lost every time the control is redrawn, since during the paint event, you are only drawing the initial points, nothing more.

Comment: you mean i should make the initial points using Graphics gfx = Panel1.CreateGraphics(); and should not use Graphics gfx = e.CreateGraphics()

Comment: No, it's the opposite. You have to draw both the points and the lines during the paint event.

Comment: nope, i cannot do that, well i have temporarily fixed the problem by making a rectangle of same color of the panel.

Comment: As I said, you *have* to draw everything on paint event. If you can't do that for a certain reason, then don't draw the lines.

Comment: well i found the problem, sorry i am unable to understand what you said, you may be right, and thanks for your help.